# Как перенести ssh-ключ на новую систему

Tags: ubuntu, ssh-key

Ключ ssh был сгенерирован давно, сейчас переустановил систему. Возник вопрос: как добавить готовый ключ на своё железо?

Моя система: ubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: Открыть на старом компьютере папку ~ зайти в .ssh и достать оттуда id_rsa и id_rsa.pub - скопировать их на новый в ~/.ssh и проставить права на файлы 0600 - а вообще вопрос частный, наверняка Александр Баракин уже писал и подскажет хороший дубликат на эту тему.

Comment: @AK, я уже решил вопрос генерацией нового ключа.
 Добавте ваш вариант как ответ - отмечу)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ключи хранятся в папке .ssh домашнего каталога.

Файлов ключа два, как правило ключи имеют наименования id_rsa и id_rsa.pub - это значения для дефолтного ключа.

Для того, чтобы восстановить ключ - просто перенесите его со старой машины на новую.

Важно: на файл id_rsa права должны быть 600 - иначе ключ будет отвергаться утилитами.

Comment: Уточнение: права 600 должны быть только у `id_rsa`, потому что это приватный ключ. `id_rsa.pub` можно раздавать направо и налево, и его права не имеют значения

Comment: @andreymal Кстати да, спасибо за уточнение.